# Vue can't set inputs after receiving response from request

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-modal, vue-resource

I'm new to Vue.js and I have problem with binding on vue-bootstrap modal. I have a form inside vue-bootstrap-modal, and there is a field with NIP number, and onChange watcher bound to this field. And this watcher sends a request and I would like to set response of that request to other inputs, something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <form>
    <input 
           name="model1"
           v-model="model1">

    <input 
           name="model1"
           v-model="model2">
  </form>

</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
        model1: '',
    model2: ''
  },
  watch: {
    model1: function(todo){
        Vue.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').then((response) => {
      console.log('response', 'response')
      this.model2 = 'test'
      })
    }
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8cdsnL91/95/

Here it is working perfectly, but on inside my bootstrap modal the values are setting after I make change to this input. So I write 10digit number, method is sending a request, I receive response, and trying to set response to the models, and when I try to console.log model the values are there, but the view updates after I interact with form. In AngularJS, I would need to use something like `$scope.$apply()`. Any help?

Comment: You could try `vm.$forceUpdate();` but there's a good chance that there is an actual issue causing this behavior.  Without being able to see the relevant code it'll be tough to determine your root cause.

Comment: I had model `form.payment.companyName` when i change it to just `companyName` everything was ok. I guess that is just a bug